# On which server should I execute the ssh port forwarding command?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a Macbook`A`, a public server`B(public IP: 1.2.3.4, internal IP: 10.0.0.2)`, an internal server`C(internal IP: 10.0.0.3)`

`A` can connect to `B` by B's public IP and `B` can connect to `C` by C's private IP, but `A` cannot directly connect to `C`

Now I want to connect to `C:2345` from `A`, so I think I can do port forwarding in `B:1234=>C:2345`?

What command should I run and on which server should I run?

I tried:

`ssh -NfR 1234:localhost:2345 10.0.0.3

ssh -L 1234:0.0.0.0:2345 10.0.0.3`

Neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do *exactly* what you requested (`B:1234=>C:2345`) this should be run on `B`:

```
# Not recommended. Read along.
ssh -NgL 1.2.3.4:1234:localhost:2345 10.0.0.3
```

It also requires opening the `1234` port in `B` firewall. Then connect to `1.2.3.4:1234` from the outside to get to `10.0.0.3:2345` as if you were connecting from the `C` itself (via its loopback interface). Anyone can connect, so keep that in mind if the server on `C` (whatever server it is) is not password protected or so.

---

An easier and a lot more secure way to get from `A` to `C` is as follows. It doesn't do exactly what you requested but it probably is what you want. On `A`:

```
ssh -NL 1234:10.0.0.3:2345 1.2.3.4
```

Then connect to `127.0.0.1:1234` on `A` to get to the port `2345` on `C`. `C` will see the traffic coming in from `B`. This connection is available to `A` only, so the method is way more secure than the previous one.

If you want to allow other computers (say: from LAN where `A` is) to connect, you should use `-g` option and specify the bind address. E.g.:

```
ssh -NgL A_LAN_address_here:1234:10.0.0.3:2345 1.2.3.4
```

In this case reconfigure the firewall on `A` accordingly, then connect to `A_LAN_address_here:1234`.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac you first do

```
ssh -L2345:10.0.0.3:2345 10.0.0.2
```

This opens a local port 2345 on your Mac that is a direct connection to :2345 on 10.0.0.3

Then you just access `127.0.0.1:2345` on your Mac.  Anything going to this port will be tunnelled over ssh and go to `10.0.0.3:2345`.  To that server, it will appear to be coming from `10.0.0.2`.

Comment: Do I need to run any command on `B`? Above command does not work. Because I cannot connect to `C` directly from A. It says: `ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.3 port 22: Operation timed out
`

Comment: Sorry, I got the IPs switched, edited.